# pyexiv2 not found but already installed with homebrew on Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyexiv2

I have installed pyexiv2 on OSX El Capitan with homebrew but when trying to use it, it is not found.

```
$ brew install pyexiv2
Warning: pyexiv2-0.3.2_1 already installed

$ python mapillary_tools-master/python/geotag_from_gpx.py photos file.gpx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nighto/Downloads/mapillary_tools-master/python/geotag_from_gpx.py", line 6, in <module>
import pyexiv2
ImportError: No module named pyexiv2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when pyexiv2 was installed, brew had a quite significant output that I missed:

```
==> Caveats
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not 
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p /Users/YOUR_USER/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/YOUR_USER/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

So you just have to run those two commands and it will work fine.